# How to control what actions are available for a device in Home Assistant?

Tags: home-assistant

How can I control what actions are available for a device in Home Assistant? I need activate the "brightness_move" action, but it does not seem to be available.

The device is a Nordtronic dimmer, and I get this error message:

```
Message malformed:  

value must be one of ['brightness_decrease', 'brightness_increase', 'flash', 'toggle', 'turn_off', 'turn_on'] for dictionary value @ data['type']
```

Note: From the [specsheet](http://zigbee2mqtt.io/devices/98425031.html): "move: this will automatically move the value over time, to stop send value stop or 0.". I would like to use this because it turns the brightness all the way up or down without turning on the light. I just want the light to be less bright when I turn it on at night so that it is not so blinding and does not wake me up so much.

Comment: what's a `brightness_move` action?

Comment: @jsotola: From the specsheet(link below): "move: this will automatically move the value over time, to stop send value stop or 0." https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/devices/98425031.html I would like to use this because it turns the brightness all the way up or down without turning on the light. I just want the light to be less bright when I turn it on at night so that it is not so blinding and does not wake me up so much.